# Using the MongoDB Ruby driver in Rails? (without an object mapper)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3

I have recently been getting my feet wet in MongoDB using Mongoid w/ Rails 3, but I'm now interested in learning the low level MongoDB features using only the Ruby driver, and trying some map/reduce that would not be possible through Mongoid (afaik)

I'm not entirely sure where in Rails I should be setting up the db connections etc, and any pointers would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out the docs over at mongodb

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Rails+-+Getting+Started

I have no personal experience with mongo (hopefully soon), i've only watched some online presentations so far, looks really cool!

**EDIT:** this one looks like its specific to the ruby driver 
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Ruby+Tutorial

some other resources I have been checking out over the last month you might find useful?

- http://www.10gen.com/event_mongosf_10apr30 (a bunch of really good presentations on mongodb; many using ruby)
- http://vimeo.com/11323139 (Schema Design with MongoDB) this one takes a few minutes to get going and the sound and video quality are not the best, but has good info
- if I recall most map/reduce can be handled via javascript functions that get passed to the mongodb server, see below screen shot taken from the vimeo screen cast
  [image]

Comment: Cheers for the link! though that guide is specifically about using the MongoMapper object mapper, and I'm looking for tips on using just the Ruby mongodb driver without an object mapper

Comment: just updated above with some additional links, hopefully of some help to you?